# Blocking website access during period, but allowing some sites

Tags: firewall, web-filtering

I am trying to block all websites at certain times, while allowing some specific websites all the time. My kids should have access to their homework websites all the time, have some time set aside for fun time that they can get on their games but block it most of the time.

I've tried pfsense, which supposedly has this capability, but I haven't been able to get it to work. And most things I have read, it doesn't work well when you do get it to work.

I've looked at Ubiquity, Sophos, Netgear, DWRT, Asus, Smoothwall, and many others, and while they can have schedules to block all websites or certain websites, they don't seem to have the ability to block all websites and allow certain websites at the same time.

Does anyone know of a firewall/security gateway/proxy server that can do this?

**Edit:**
I need this to work on a network level, not a individual device level.

Currently I have a server running pfsense on FreeBSD, so a software solution to run on the server would be nice, but is not necessary. I'm willing to buy new hardware if needed. Preferably under $400USD, but I'm willing to go over that if nothing else will work.

**Edit 2:**
It doesn't have to be a firewall or security gateway. At this point I am looking for any solution.

Comment: Plaese add your OS and what you're willing to pay.

Comment: ipset create whitelist hash:net
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set whitelist src,src -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp -m tcp  -m multiport --dports 80,443  -m time --timestart 15:30 --timestop 13:30   -j DROP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I could not figure out how to make pfsense to do what I wanted it to do. Rather than continue to fight it, I ended up buying a router from [Gryphon Connect](https://gryphonconnect.com/) that allows me to do what I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup proxy server to restrict access on certain websites.**squid** is powerful utility that may be helpful for you.You can restrict access on certain time or even you can use regex.Try to install in **RHEL** or in **Debian**. Following are two links that may help you.
1) [squid installation on centos-7](https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-http-proxy-on-centos-7/)
2) [squid installation on debian](https://tecadmin.net/install-squid-debian9/)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I'm already using squid in pfsense. I've tried many different solutions to use squid, but none of them have worked.

Comment: may be problem is in squid.conf .If you post squid.conf may be someone can help. :)